# Type hinting – Difference between `Closure` and `Callable`

Tags: php

I noticed that I can use either of `Closure` or `Callable` as type hint if we expected some callback function to run. For example:

```
function callFunc1(Closure $closure) {
    $closure();
}

function callFunc2(Callable $callback) {
    $callback();
}

$function = function() {
    echo 'Hello, World!';
};

callFunc1($function); // Hello, World!
callFunc2($function); // Hello, World!
```

##### Question

What's the difference here? In other words when to use `Closure` and when to use `Callable` *or* do they serve the same purpose?

Comment: Note for readers of this question and the answers herein: there are some references to `Callback` (upper case). This is incorrect. It's just `callback` (lower case), which is a type hint. It's not a class. Conversely, `Closure` is an actual class that exists in the global namespace, and should therefore be capitalised.

Comment: @BadHorsie - while I agree in principle that we should do it like that, PHP is case insensitive for type names and it will work either way.

Comment: @Davor Yes maybe, but also if you use an IDE it may not recognise the one with incorrect case because it doesn't actually reference anything properly.

Answer (score 244, accepted):

The difference is, that a [`Closure`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php) must be an anonymous function, where [`callable`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) also can be a normal function.

You can see/test this with the example below and you will see that you will get an error for the first one:

```
function callFunc1(Closure $closure) {
    $closure();
}

function callFunc2(Callable $callback) {
    $callback();
}

function xy() {
    echo 'Hello, World!';
}

callFunc1("xy"); // Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to callFunc1() must be an instance of Closure, string given
callFunc2("xy"); // Hello, World!
```

So if you only want to type hint anonymous function use: `Closure` and if you want also to allow normal functions use `callable` as type hint.

Comment: You can also use class methods with callable by passing an array, e.g. `["Foo", "bar"]` for `Foo::bar` or `[$foo, "bar"]` for `$foo->bar`.

Comment: Offtopic, but related: since PHP 7.1, you can now easily convert to a Closure: `callFunc1(Closure::fromCallable("xy"))`. https://wiki.php.net/rfc/closurefromcallable

Comment: I still don't see why would I want to call anonymous function only. If I share the code, I shouldn't care where the function comes from. I consider that one of PHP's quirks, they should remove one or another way to avoid confusion. But I honestly like the `Closure` + `Closure::fromCallable` approach, because string or array as `callable` has always been weird.

Comment: @RoboRobok one reason for requiring only `Closure` (anonymous function) as opposed to `callable`, would be to prevent access beyond the scope of the called function. For example when you have a `private method` you do not want accessed by someone abusing a `callable`. See: https://3v4l.org/7TSf2

Comment: For anyone trying to assign a default function for the `$closure` or `$callback` input parameters, you need to set `null` as the default value and do a check for `null` inside the function itself, and assign the default function there if the parameter is `null`. It's not possible to provide a default `Closure` or `callable`. This is because default values can only be scalar values (string, int, float, null) or arrays. This is poorly documented, so hopefully this saves someone from excessive searching.

Comment: Extending @nevvermind comment above in a class you can do this ```Closure::fromCallable([$this, 'functionName']);```

Comment: You can also now use the PHP 8.1 `(...)` syntax to return a Closure from a regular function, eg `callFunc2(xy(...));` or `$this->funcName(...)` for classes.

Answer (score 90):

The main difference between them is that a [`closure`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php) is a *class* and [`callable`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) a *type*.

The `callable` type accepts anything that can be [called](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php):

```
var_dump(
  is_callable('functionName'),
  is_callable([$myClass, 'methodName']),
  is_callable(function(){})
); // all true
```

Where a `closure` will ***only*** accept an anonymous function. Note that in PHP version 7.1 you can convert functions to a closure like so:
[`Closure::fromCallable('functionName')`](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.fromcallable.php).

---

### Example:

```
namespace foo{
  class bar{
    private $baz = 10;

    function myCallable(callable $cb){$cb()}
    function myClosure(\Closure $cb){$cb()} // type hint must refer to global namespace
  }

  function func(){}
  $cb = function(){};
  $fb = new bar;

  $fb->myCallable(function(){});
  $fb->myCallable($cb);
  $fb->myCallable('func');

  $fb->myClosure(function(){});
  $fb->myClosure($cb);
  $fb->myClosure(\Closure::fromCallable('func'));
  $fb->myClosure('func'); # TypeError
}
```

### So why use a `closure` over `callable`?

Strictness because a `closure` is an object that has some additional methods: [`call()`](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.call.php), [`bind()`](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bind.php) and [`bindto()`](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php). They allow you to use a function declared outside of a class and execute it as if it was inside a class:

```
$inject = function($i){return $this->baz * $i;};
$cb1 = \Closure::bind($inject, $fb);
$cb2 = $inject->bindTo($fb);

echo $cb1->call($fb, 2); // 20
echo $cb2(3);            // 30
```

You would not like to call methods on a normal function as that will raise fatal errors. So in order to circumvent that you would have to write something like:

```
if($cb instanceof \Closure){}
```

To do this check every time is pointless. So if you want to use those methods state that the argument is a `closure`. Otherwise just use a normal `callback`. This way; An error is raised on function call instead of your code causing it making it much easier to diagnose.

*On a side note:* The `closure` class cannot be extended as its [final](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php).

Comment: You can reuse a callable in other scopes as well.

Comment: This means you don't have to qualify `callable` in any namespace.

Answer (score -1):

It's worth mentioning that this won't work for PHP versions 5.3.21 to 5.3.29.

In any of those versions you will get an output like:

> Hello, World!
> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to callFunc2() must be an instance of > Callable, instance of Closure given, called in /in/kqeYD on line 16 and defined in /in/kqeYD on line 7
>
> Process exited with code 255.

One can try that out using https://3v4l.org/kqeYD#v5321

Best regards,

Comment: Instead of posting a link to the code, you should post the code here in case someone else runs into this problem and the link you've provided breaks.  You can also provide the output in your post to help.

Comment: This is because `callable` was introduced in PHP 5.4. Prior to that PHP is expecting an instance of a class named `callable`, just as if you'd specified a hint for `PDO`, `DateTime`, or `\My\Random\ClassName`.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why did you expect that this should work?