# What is the PHP7 type of a closure?

Tags: php, php-7, signature, php-7.2

Here's the code, it's a simple container.

```
class Application
{
  private $recipes;
  private $instances;

  public function configureCache(XXXXXXXX $closure) {
    $recipes['cache'] = $closure;
  }

  public function getCache(): Cache {
    if (empty($instances['cache'])) {
      $instances['cache'] = $recipes['cache']();
    }
    return $instances['cache'];
  }
}
```

This code runs on PHP 7.1+. What can I fill in for XXXXXXXX to make it the most specific? The type is a function and more specifically a function that returns a Cache.

Comment: is this it? http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php

Comment: what about http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Comment: Not 100% sure, which is why I'm not posting it as an answer, but I think the correct type hint in this case is "callable" if you want it to be able to accept anonymous functions

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29730720/1941241

Comment: Use `get_class` and type hint to what it returns...?

Comment: It's also worth noting that despite PHP naming the class "Closure" PHP does not have actual closures as you might expect from other languages, in that scope in which it is declared is *not* imported into, nor otherwise made available to, the anonymous function.

Comment: @Sammitch I'd modify that a bit: in PHP, scope imports are always explicit, so closures have to *explicitly* import the variables they want to use, with the `use` clause. The variables imported with `use` act exactly as you'd expect a closure to work, and can be captured by value or reference at the user's discretion.

Answer (score 7):

PHP supports several syntaxes for callable entities: string containing function name, array of object and method, array of class and method in case of static methods, first class closures, and generated closures.

The type hint for all these is `callable`.

If you want only anonymous functions, ie first class closures, use `Closure`. But that would limit the kinds of callable you could accept.

As of now, PHP does not support argument hints or return type hints on formal callable arguments: your code cannot say, for example, only accept closures that take one string parameter and return boolean.

Comment: I guess what I really want is the PHP functions ported over to Swift

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want to force someone to pass an anonymous function, then it will always be an instance of [the Closure class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php).

If what you actually want is "something you can use like a function", you can use the [callable pseudo-type](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php), which accepts both closures and the various string and array notations for references to named functions and methods.

You can also convert any callable into a Closure instance using [Closure::fromCallable](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.fromcallable.php).

Unfortunately, you can't get any more specific than that; there have been proposals for hinting particular signatures for callables, or allowing them to meet specially crafted interface definitions, but none has been adopted as yet.

You could however require an object implementing a normal interface with one method, and I believe that method could be [the magic __invoke method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.invoke). The caller could then use an [anonymous class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php) instead of an anonymous function:

```
interface CacheFactory {
    public function __invoke(): Cache;
} 
$app->configureCache(new class implements CacheFactory {
    public function __invoke(): Cache {
          return new Cache;
    }
});
```

Note that the resulting object would itself pass a `callable` type hint as well as `CacheFactory`, and can be used just like the anonymous function in your example.

Even with this solution, however, the type is only checked *at runtime*, so this code will not raise any errors in itself, and you will just receive a type error 10% of the time *when you actually run the callback*:

```
$app->configureCache(new class implements CacheFactory {
    public function __invoke(): Cache {
          return rand(0,10) > 9 ? "Nonsense" : new Cache;
    }
});
```

Most of the time, you probably just want `callable` and some good documentation.