# Is there any way to return a function imported with use interface?

Tags: php, import

I am fairly new to PHP so i have stumbled with this issue.

I have an index file with a dispatching function. I want to return either the rendering functions or the whole modules which are imported with use.

```
use function App\renders\deepRender\render as deepRendering;
use function App\renders\plainRender\render as plainRendering;
use App\renders\deepRender;
use App\renders\plainRender;

function getRenderMethod($renderType)
{
    $renderers = [
        "pretty" => deepRender, //or using deepRendering
        "plain" => plainRender, //or using  plainRendering
    ];

    // i have tried returning it like that.
    return $renderers[$renderType];
```

Then in other place i would try to

```
$renderer = getRenderMethod($renderType);
$renderer\render();
```

But that doesn't work. I have tried also running the functions from cb when the the $renderers array inholds the functions directly.

```
return function ($ast) use ($renderers, $renderType) {
    $renderer = $renderers[$renderType];
    return $renderer($ast);
};
```

Is there anyway to make this work without using classes?

Comment: You could try returning a closure. https://www.php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php

Comment: I should not use classes

Comment: There is another way to do it with callables for non-method functions.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29730720/php-type-hinting-difference-between-closure-and-callable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was:

```
use function App\renders\deepRender\render as deepRendering;
use function App\renders\plainRender\render as plainRendering;

function getRenderMethod($renderType)
{
    $renderers = [
        "pretty" => function ($ast) {
            return deepRendering($ast);
        },
        "plain" => function ($ast) {
            return plainRendering($ast);
        },
    ];
    return $renderers[$renderType];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't have any concept of "modules". Namespaces are just ways of grouping things by name, and don't imply any other relationship. A `use` statement at the top of a file just allows you to write a shorter name *within the current file* which is expanded when compiling the code.

As such, you can't pass around a reference to a namespace, because a namespace isn't really a thing, it's just part of the name of the things "inside" it. You could pass around a *string* that contains the namespace prefix, but it would need to contain *the full prefix*, not an alias introduced in the current file by a `use` statement.

A more useful approach is to pass around something which has a "first-class" existence within the language, namely:

- An object. Your two rendering modes could be instances of objects implementing a particular interface. The interface would specify that the object must have a `render` method, and rather than writing `$renderer\render();` you would write `$renderer->render();`
- An anonymous function. In this case, your two rendering modes would simply be defined as a function with no name, that was called directly as `$renderer()`. This approach is most useful if the implementation is small, rather than a whole "module".